# compress html and css of a page on click on button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am making a project in which i want a feature for user that he/she can download the html page . Suppose there is a page `home.php` and there is a button `download` and in that page there are some js files included which helps in tabs and navigation . I wanted to know if its possible to establish a way using php , javascript or jquery in which a user can click on a button and the whole page gets downloaded in form of html and all the external js file codes and css file codes get compressed inside that file which is to be downloaded and user can then open it easily offline too ?

Comment: Yes, it is called "Save page as ... html" and most browsers have it

Comment: We need to see code to attempt to assist you. We aren't here to theorize about possibilities, as that's out of the scope.

Comment: I dont want to zip a file . I want to compress the whole js coming from another file into the same file and just make a download button to download that whole page as just one html file with all compressed js and css within that file as inline instead of external